# C# read der encoded private key

Tags: c#, asn.1, der

How can I get the fields from ASN1 DER format private key? Is there a library to decode and get the fields separately?

I need to extract the modulus, exponent and all the other fields.

Or maybe is there a way to convert it to .net xml format?

Comment: Have a look at the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) library. I've used it on a previous project for similar sorts of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to it, I used the code from this utility:
http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/

And the source code: [OpenSSLKey](http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/opensslkey.cs)

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to reduce the code needed to parse ASN.1, you could have a peek at the LCLib portion of the [ASN.1 Editor project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-1-Editor).

It is a simple ASN.1 processor library.

Using the sample DER encoded test string of "test1@rsa.com" :

16 0d 74 65 73 74 31 40 72 73 61 2e 63 6f 6d

```
    using (var stm = new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 0x16, 0x0d, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x31, 0x40, 0x72, 0x73, 0x61, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d }))
    {
        Asn1Parser parser = new Asn1Parser();
        parser.LoadData(stm);
        var decoded = parser.ToString();
    }
```

Gives the formatted output:

> Offset| Len  |LenByte|
>   ======+======+=======+====
>
> ```
>  0|    13|      1| IA5 STRING : 'test1@rsa.com'
> ```

You can walk the tree, and process the nodes as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

The usual [private key](https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/cms/files/xsdf.key) you have comes as PEM DER ASN.1 as:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

It is the **BEGIN PRIVATE KEY** header that tells you this is going to be data in the **PrivateKeyInfo** format.

```
PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version                   Version,
    privateKeyAlgorithm       PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier,
    privateKey                PrivateKey,
    attributes           [0]  IMPLICIT Attributes OPTIONAL 
}
```

The `PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier` tells you what kind of private key is to follow (e.g. EC, RSA, DH). In the case of RSA the Algorithm ID is

- `1.2.840.113549.1.1.1`: rsaEncryption (PKCS #1)

This means it has the following structure:

```
  RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
      version           Version,
      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
      publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
      privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
      prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
      prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
      exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
      exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
      coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
      otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
  }
```

The data is base64 encoded, which we can decode:

```
30 82 04 be 02 01 00 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 00 04 82 04 a8 30 82 04 a4 02 01 00 02 82 01 01 00 bb 75 3c 47 bf 36 68 10 a6 63 64 98 98 33 6c 4b d2 86 ab 27 22 d6 22 d5 66 06 0e 94 30 d2 7f 38 a6 19 f3 7f be 90 24 08 c1 33 3c 30 b0 7c 14 10 42 fa ac c6 3b ce f9 e4 84 4d b9 7a 1d a7 35 ee 71 7c b5 fb cd d4 92 64 70 61 5f 7b 16 f1 b1 11 4b 99 fd f9 0e 69 dd 18 e9 48 88 43 59 92 45 68 61 d2 d7 86 71 77 46 f0 b2 82 bf c1 ec ad 20 a1 8e 70 36 a1 9b f3 1a 2a a5 4f 93 9f 35 dc 9e 72 5b 59 cb c1 4e c9 e1 eb 4a d3 3e e0 c0 fd 57 6d 0a d8 6a 7b 57 bb 3c b3 04 d2 30 58 af d2 24 ef b8 f8 24 d1 5c 68 24 2f 07 e7 25 90 fe a4 29 14 2d 8c 7f ff d2 df 73 28 32 9b 03 03 af e3 2e 2e 92 9c c7 a7 12 22 29 f5 97 56 ac bb 76 47 f7 d7 1e fe c5 02 89 61 a1 0f 18 ea e5 4d 32 fd ec 9a f3 02 2f 78 ec f2 f4 f8 83 85 09 84 f6 6a e9 d8 45 b7 ab 79 69 8b 31 5d 85 12 1e 9e 05 01 c4 9f 02 03 01 00 01 02 82 01 00 76 b3 7e cf 43 c2 54 d5 2e 37 43 ec e8 7b af 78 b7 bf b4 c3 1c 69 12 37 a4 d9 f3 03 5d 82 fd 32 46 e3 a9 ef db 20 74 e0 e2 4d ea 30 3e a0 e3 27 84 f2 2c d3 7d ed cb 09 2b c9 f7 c7 de dd 11 e6 82 10 61 40 28 8f 11 7f ee 35 8a 7b 6c 04 f1 85 ad 24 be d0 a5 92 dd 81 37 bf 49 21 b4 a7 4d b2 12 37 ab 68 23 93 4e e5 7d 74 13 ae dd 8a a7 5e 05 cf 02 99 05 22 44 10 7b 0b 4f c4 02 1c 48 6b b4 b6 c5 f9 a4 03 37 6a 88 e4 4b 08 17 cc 70 0a 37 4d c2 5f 9b 9b 62 44 4c b0 c9 71 ff 5d 3f 80 d0 78 c7 63 95 74 f0 12 e4 27 ef cd fd 6f 40 89 6a 13 25 a7 ac 69 da cd 0e 80 56 26 db f5 91 d9 8e 37 16 f8 70 7d 0b fc 6b d3 15 ce 5e cd df a2 4f ef a5 16 3d 87 a6 f8 6c 7b b6 37 fe 3b df 9a 75 03 f4 cf 76 7b 2d f0 5d 61 a4 80 26 78 ba e7 4c a5 50 16 24 18 38 c5 32 2d ab d3 23 e5 b3 89 02 81 81 00 f1 53 67 ea 82 13 3d 54 89 4d 12 ee 6a a0 24 7b 56 3f 31 87 5b 2e d0 73 81 76 f2 f2 84 d5 70 b8 68 28 43 bf 41 9b 20 e6 42 a1 2b b9 a5 13 c4 01 64 a2 b0 89 1c 09 4e ef 24 cb 37 a6 79 a6 81 e3 3e 21 a6 79 2b 8f 78 12 ab 89 49 f9 09 fb 16 53 42 f9 fb 50 51 5f 0f 90 be 6d 82 50 93 b8 4c e3 9a 66 0e b4 bb 18 ae 39 bc 1b 4a 55 69 10 16 79 a6 00 f6 09 6d 9a 99 a6 c0 b8 cf cd da 6f 6c 5d 02 81 81 00 c6 db 4b e8 5b 30 81 60 f7 d4 4e 73 e0 a5 b5 56 33 1b e1 51 06 5b 64 d1 0d ee ac 83 65 a0 5e ad c5 02 af bc 84 f6 8b 53 8d 62 86 87 21 06 78 f1 f9 a9 7d 60 55 52 98 9f 79 1a 86 91 74 77 27 96 fa 56 90 db 3d e5 59 16 e8 2d 95 ae 27 9a 50 c1 9e 41 b7 9a 8d 27 1d 93 22 29 53 71 74 f5 f9 19 b4 46 aa 8b 62 5d d1 57 ce 96 5d dc 8b 6e 4c 5e f4 1f c5 89 07 48 33 fe 09 24 f7 23 07 13 c5 2b 02 81 80 2e 1d ee 41 d6 51 ae ea b4 c2 51 d7 d5 f0 7c 88 45 57 16 33 f3 ac e2 90 f0 30 b7 04 b9 75 c0 70 bd 16 d4 bb 7b e2 15 4b 6b 78 39 4e e4 c8 fe 2f f5 f7 51 1d 22 8a 74 d7 26 84 df 41 a5 05 b8 d4 a0 4e f5 ed 39 f1 d4 d4 5c 8b 83 e3 5f 90 e8 17 49 39 54 59 68 f3 6d 9a 0f 8a 05 d9 38 21 84 30 0a 95 6e 42 03 6f 17 fc 58 82 2e 96 5b d9 83 32 04 13 32 f1 62 4c a5 08 44 d4 0c 82 1e 38 24 d1 02 81 81 00 89 ec 2a 0e e3 c8 95 c3 ba c0 7f 15 71 f7 9c f9 47 83 8b d8 55 cf 67 f2 73 76 5a 22 dc 86 c9 84 3e c3 a9 3d d8 fe e3 0d b5 5f 63 ad 2f a3 bc 99 20 2f 85 2d 1e a0 a6 08 dd c7 1f 14 9d b1 d3 3c ad 2f 03 53 7c ef a8 c5 f1 8d 44 66 c1 43 0f c5 ea cc eb da 7f 12 65 39 da 94 cd 32 41 0c 25 94 c5 6b c9 f7 d8 e6 f7 3e ae a3 ae 40 3c 58 e9 11 66 c2 ee 90 27 03 d6 43 d8 f5 d1 8f 72 e6 2c 77 02 81 81 00 af cf 22 dc 29 75 b6 e3 d8 6e 81 25 e7 42 80 1f ca 6b b1 fa 92 be f1 8c 46 d6 be 35 c0 f7 34 f3 4a 74 bd 0b 1b 2a 54 ec 96 75 11 22 8c e1 9d 82 49 24 df 01 41 e2 84 5c a3 c6 48 95 ca f4 1e 37 a5 44 8e 9a 1e 9a 01 75 72 07 ae 2c b1 5d b3 52 6d 78 7c 24 ca 7c 96 39 81 bb 92 aa af 6c 54 8d 0b 0e 4d e9 57 e7 1f d5 5a fa a6 c8 8f 0c 4c 59 33 ea 9d 50 61 43 f2 a9 3c 5f 66 fb 9d b2 bb 0e
```

Which knowing it is DER ASN.1, we can start to decode:

- **SEQUENCE** (0x4be bytes): `30 82 04 be`

  - **INTEGER** (1 byte): `02 01`

    - `Version`: 0 `00`
  - **SEQUENCE** (0x0d bytes): `30 0d`

    - `PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier`: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 `06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01`
    - *null* (0 bytes): `05 00`
  - **OCTET STRING** (0x04a8 bytes): `04 82 04 a8`

    - **SEQUENCE** (0x04a4 bytes) `30 82 04 a4`

      - **INTEGER** (1 byte) `02 01`

        - `Version`: 0 `00`
      - **INTEGER** (0x0101 bytes) `02 82 01 01`

        - `modulus` `00 bb 75 3c 47 bf 36 68 10 a6 63 64 98 98 33 6c 4b d2 86 ab 27 22 d6 22 d5 66 06 0e 94 30 d2 7f 38 a6 19 f3 7f be 90 24 08 c1 33 3c 30 b0 7c 14 10 42 fa ac c6 3b ce f9 e4 84 4d b9 7a 1d a7 35 ee 71 7c b5 fb cd d4 92 64 70 61 5f 7b 16 f1 b1 11 4b 99 fd f9 0e 69 dd 18 e9 48 88 43 59 92 45 68 61 d2 d7 86 71 77 46 f0 b2 82 bf c1 ec ad 20 a1 8e 70 36 a1 9b f3 1a 2a a5 4f 93 9f 35 dc 9e 72 5b 59 cb c1 4e c9 e1 eb 4a d3 3e e0 c0 fd 57 6d 0a d8 6a 7b 57 bb 3c b3 04 d2 30 58 af d2 24 ef b8 f8 24 d1 5c 68 24 2f 07 e7 25 90 fe a4 29 14 2d 8c 7f ff d2 df 73 28 32 9b 03 03 af e3 2e 2e 92 9c c7 a7 12 22 29 f5 97 56 ac bb 76 47 f7 d7 1e fe c5 02 89 61 a1 0f 18 ea e5 4d 32 fd ec 9a f3 02 2f 78 ec f2 f4 f8 83 85 09 84 f6 6a e9 d8 45 b7 ab 79 69 8b 31 5d 85 12 1e 9e 05 01 c4 9f`
      - **INTEGER** (3 bytes) `02 03`

        - `publicExponent`: `01 00 01`
      - **INTEGER** (0x0100 bytes) `02 82 01 00`

        - `privateExponent`: `76 b3 7e cf 43 c2 54 d5 2e 37 43 ec e8 7b af 78 b7 bf b4 c3 1c 69 12 37 a4 d9 f3 03 5d 82 fd 32 46 e3 a9 ef db 20 74 e0 e2 4d ea 30 3e a0 e3 27 84 f2 2c d3 7d ed cb 09 2b c9 f7 c7 de dd 11 e6 82 10 61 40 28 8f 11 7f ee 35 8a 7b 6c 04 f1 85 ad 24 be d0 a5 92 dd 81 37 bf 49 21 b4 a7 4d b2 12 37 ab 68 23 93 4e e5 7d 74 13 ae dd 8a a7 5e 05 cf 02 99 05 22 44 10 7b 0b 4f c4 02 1c 48 6b b4 b6 c5 f9 a4 03 37 6a 88 e4 4b 08 17 cc 70 0a 37 4d c2 5f 9b 9b 62 44 4c b0 c9 71 ff 5d 3f 80 d0 78 c7 63 95 74 f0 12 e4 27 ef cd fd 6f 40 89 6a 13 25 a7 ac 69 da cd 0e 80 56 26 db f5 91 d9 8e 37 16 f8 70 7d 0b fc 6b d3 15 ce 5e cd df a2 4f ef a5 16 3d 87 a6 f8 6c 7b b6 37 fe 3b df 9a 75 03 f4 cf 76 7b 2d f0 5d 61 a4 80 26 78 ba e7 4c a5 50 16 24 18 38 c5 32 2d ab d3 23 e5 b3 89`
      - **INTEGER** (0x81 bytes) `02 81 81`

        - `prime1`: `00 f1 53 67 ea 82 13 3d 54 89 4d 12 ee 6a a0 24 7b 56 3f 31 87 5b 2e d0 73 81 76 f2 f2 84 d5 70 b8 68 28 43 bf 41 9b 20 e6 42 a1 2b b9 a5 13 c4 01 64 a2 b0 89 1c 09 4e ef 24 cb 37 a6 79 a6 81 e3 3e 21 a6 79 2b 8f 78 12 ab 89 49 f9 09 fb 16 53 42 f9 fb 50 51 5f 0f 90 be 6d 82 50 93 b8 4c e3 9a 66 0e b4 bb 18 ae 39 bc 1b 4a 55 69 10 16 79 a6 00 f6 09 6d 9a 99 a6 c0 b8 cf cd da 6f 6c 5d`
      - **INTEGER** (0x81 bytes) `02 81 81`

        - `prime2`: `00 c6 db 4b e8 5b 30 81 60 f7 d4 4e 73 e0 a5 b5 56 33 1b e1 51 06 5b 64 d1 0d ee ac 83 65 a0 5e ad c5 02 af bc 84 f6 8b 53 8d 62 86 87 21 06 78 f1 f9 a9 7d 60 55 52 98 9f 79 1a 86 91 74 77 27 96 fa 56 90 db 3d e5 59 16 e8 2d 95 ae 27 9a 50 c1 9e 41 b7 9a 8d 27 1d 93 22 29 53 71 74 f5 f9 19 b4 46 aa 8b 62 5d d1 57 ce 96 5d dc 8b 6e 4c 5e f4 1f c5 89 07 48 33 fe 09 24 f7 23 07 13 c5 2b`
      - **INTEGER** (0x80 bytes) `02 81 80`

        - `exponent1`: `2e 1d ee 41 d6 51 ae ea b4 c2 51 d7 d5 f0 7c 88 45 57 16 33 f3 ac e2 90 f0 30 b7 04 b9 75 c0 70 bd 16 d4 bb 7b e2 15 4b 6b 78 39 4e e4 c8 fe 2f f5 f7 51 1d 22 8a 74 d7 26 84 df 41 a5 05 b8 d4 a0 4e f5 ed 39 f1 d4 d4 5c 8b 83 e3 5f 90 e8 17 49 39 54 59 68 f3 6d 9a 0f 8a 05 d9 38 21 84 30 0a 95 6e 42 03 6f 17 fc 58 82 2e 96 5b d9 83 32 04 13 32 f1 62 4c a5 08 44 d4 0c 82 1e 38 24 d1`
      - **INTEGER** (0x81 bytes) `02 81 81`

        - `exponent2`: `00 89 ec 2a 0e e3 c8 95 c3 ba c0 7f 15 71 f7 9c f9 47 83 8b d8 55 cf 67 f2 73 76 5a 22 dc 86 c9 84 3e c3 a9 3d d8 fe e3 0d b5 5f 63 ad 2f a3 bc 99 20 2f 85 2d 1e a0 a6 08 dd c7 1f 14 9d b1 d3 3c ad 2f 03 53 7c ef a8 c5 f1 8d 44 66 c1 43 0f c5 ea cc eb da 7f 12 65 39 da 94 cd 32 41 0c 25 94 c5 6b c9 f7 d8 e6 f7 3e ae a3 ae 40 3c 58 e9 11 66 c2 ee 90 27 03 d6 43 d8 f5 d1 8f 72 e6 2c 77`
      - **INTEGER** (0x81 bytes) `02 81 81`

        - `coefficient`: `00 af cf 22 dc 29 75 b6 e3 d8 6e 81 25 e7 42 80 1f ca 6b b1 fa 92 be f1 8c 46 d6 be 35 c0 f7 34 f3 4a 74 bd 0b 1b 2a 54 ec 96 75 11 22 8c e1 9d 82 49 24 df 01 41 e2 84 5c a3 c6 48 95 ca f4 1e 37 a5 44 8e 9a 1e 9a 01 75 72 07 ae 2c b1 5d b3 52 6d 78 7c 24 ca 7c 96 39 81 bb 92 aa af 6c 54 8d 0b 0e 4d e9 57 e7 1f d5 5a fa a6 c8 8f 0c 4c 59 33 ea 9d 50 61 43 f2 a9 3c 5f 66 fb 9d b2 bb 0e`

And so you have your final RSA Private Key values:

```
version:         0
modulus:         236643739934412948903373669476774126683629718702123314074863910669092…
publicExponent:  65,537
privateExponent: 149846324420376321261899444735289218048490924156116627413411926527864…
prime1:          169464742892393599674909179163866779357332259972872392530945213283668…
prime2:          139641872341951706778976733766729896659299032766950485174897609653257…
exponent1:       323844002622081792320149314104745036341490947693707957956201512300634… 
exponent2:       968524849673225022756364715102416566618618114106799869329534590657009… 
coefficient:     123457366510080958921249047966574081489759226696746456882235437625391…
```